# Libreoffice crashes on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, libreoffice

After release upgrading from 19.10 to 20.04 libreoffice now crashes no matter what I try to open. There is not output when running `libreoffice` from the command line. It also crashes via `libreoffice --safe-mode`.

Answer (score 2):

My next step was going to be reinstalling the packages, but upon looking through apt I noticed I did not have the meta package installed. Checked with:

```
aptitude search libreoffice | grep ^i
```

Running the following fixed it for me:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your suggested fix, but it didn't work for me. It's only one family of files that Libreoffice calc crashes on. I can open others just fine. Unfortunately, this is the one I track my investments on daily. I open old copies from last year and it still crashes, so it's not some glitch in the file. The file has about 12 worksheets with a lot of equations and charts and references between sheets, all self-contained in this one file, so I assume some little bit of software is tripping over something that was previously innocuous. The first time this problem happened was a few weeks ago, when I wanted to create some macros in a different file. It said I needed to install javascript, and when I did it crashed that file (with the macros) as well as this one (the investment tracking). I haven't opened the file with the macros since. I uninstalled the javascript, but it made no difference, the investment file crashes as soon as I open it, and will also crash any other libreoffice files I have open. I wiped the partition and reinstalled an image from the previous week, and everything was working fine until yesterday when I installed the update to kernel version 5.4.0-56. Now the investment file crashes immediately on opening again. I try rebooting into previous versions 5.4.0-48 and 5.4.0-47 (20.04), but now Libreoffice still crashes on this one file (and previous copies) even in these old versions. I still have a installation of Ubuntu 18.04 on another partition. I can reboot into that and open this file and everything is fine. I guess my temporary fix is to stick with 18.04 until the next kernel update, and hope whatever the problem is with Libreoffice is fixed in that.